# Display data of a searched item using Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I currently have a search bar. It searches clients that have filled a form, using first and last names, the search provides a list with the names being links to the client's page.

I am struggling to display that specific person's data, the model has about 20 fields, it would need to display all.
How could I retrieve the data of a single person and display all the data from the model?

At present the page comes up blank, the URL displays the correct client id though.

Thank you in advance.

edit:

Views.py

```
# for search
def clientSearch(request):
    query = request.GET.get('q')

    if query:
        queryset = (Q(FIRST_NAME__icontains=query))|(Q(LAST_NAME__icontains=query))
        results = Register_Client.objects.filter(queryset).distinct()
    else:
        results = []

    content = {
        'results' : results,
        'query' : query
    }

    return render(request, 'HTML/clientSearch.html', content)

# For displaying details
def client(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Register_Client, id=id)
    field = obj._meta.fields
    content = {
        "field":field
    }
    return render(request, 'HTML/Client.html', content)
```

Model:

```
class Register_Client(models.Model):
    TITLES = (
            ('MR', 'Mr'),
            ('MISS', 'Miss'),
            ('MRS', 'Mrs'),
            ('OTHER', 'Other')
    )
    TITLE = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                            choices=TITLES,
                            blank=True,
                            default=None)
    FIRST_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    LAST_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    DATE_OF_BIRTH = models.DateField()
    ADDRESS_LINE_ONE = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ADDRESS_LINE_TWO = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                        blank=True)
    CITY = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                            blank=True)
    POSTCODE = models.CharField(max_length=8)
    EMAIL = models.EmailField(blank=True)

    phone_regex = RegexValidator(regex=r'^\+?1?\d{11}$', message ="You must enter an 11 digit number")
    TEL_NUM = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=11, blank=True)
    MOBILE = models.CharField(validators=[phone_regex], max_length=11, blank=True)

    GP_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=255,
                                blank=True)
    NHS_NO = models.CharField(max_length=20,
                                blank=True)
    GP = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                            blank=True)
    GENDERS = (
                ('MALE', 'Male'),
                ('FEMALE', 'Female'),
                ('OTHER', 'Other')
                )
    GENDER = models.CharField(max_length=6,
                            choices=GENDERS,
                            blank=True,
                            default=None)
    SCHOOL = models.CharField(max_length=50,
                                blank=True)
    ETHNICITY = (
                ('WHITEB','White – British'),
                ('WHITEI','White – Irish'),
                ('WHITEO','White - Other'),
                ('MIXWBC','Mixed – White & Black Caribbean'),
                ('MIXWBA','Mixed – White & Black African'),
                ('MIXO','Mixed – Other'),
                ('AABI','Asian / Asian British - Indian'),
                ('AABP','Asian / Asian British – Pakistani'),
                ('AABB','Asian / Asian British - Bangladeshi'),
                ('AABO','Asian / Asian British – Other'),
                ('BBBA','Black/Black British – African'),
                ('BBBO','Black/Black British – Other'),
                ('C','Chinese'),
                ('O','Any Other Ethnic Group'),
                ('NOT','Not Stated'),

    )
    ETHNIC = models.CharField(max_length=40,
                            choices=ETHNICITY,
                            blank=True,
                            default=None)`
```

Comment: Paste your code (particularly the views.py and models.py)

Comment: @GrandPhuba, I've posted the code.

Comment: added an answer based on what you have provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll focus on the `client` view

Change it to the following:

```
# For displaying details
def client(request, id):
    obj = get_object_or_404(Register_Client, id=id)
    context = {
        "obj": obj
    }
    return render(request, 'HTML/Client.html', context)
```

In your template `HTML/Client.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <p>TITLES: {{ obj.TITLES }}</p>
        <p>TITLE: {{ obj.TITLE }}</p>
        <p>FIRST_NAME: {{ obj.FIRST_NAME }}</p>
        <p>LAST_NAME: {{ obj.LAST_NAME }}</p>
        <p>DATE_OF_BIRTH: {{ obj.DATE_OF_BIRTH }}</p>
        <p>ADDRESS_LINE_ONE: {{ obj.ADDRESS_LINE_ONE }}</p>
        <p>ADDRESS_LINE_TWO: {{ obj.ADDRESS_LINE_TWO }}</p>
        <p>CITY: {{ obj.CITY }}</p>
        <p>POSTCODE: {{ obj.POSTCODE }}</p>
        <p>EMAIL: {{ obj.EMAIL }}</p>
        <p>phone_regex: {{ obj.phone_regex }}</p>
        <p>TEL_NUM: {{ obj.TEL_NUM }}</p>
        <p>MOBILE: {{ obj.MOBILE }}</p>
        <p>GP_NAME: {{ obj.GP_NAME }}</p>
        <p>NHS_NO: {{ obj.NHS_NO }}</p>
        <p>GP: {{ obj.GP }}</p>
        <p>GENDERS: {{ obj.GENDERS }}</p>
        <p>GENDER: {{ obj.GENDER }}</p>
        <p>SCHOOL: {{ obj.SCHOOL }}</p>
        <p>ETHNICITY: {{ obj.ETHNICITY }}</p>
        <p>ETHNIC: {{ obj.ETHNIC }}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @JiM, Note that your code doesn't necessarily conform to python/django conventions, but I focused on the question at hand for now.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by this

Comment: It's usually best to follow certain logical and style conventions when writing software. An example is using lowercases for filed names (`first_name` vs `FIRST_NAME`),PascalCase when writing class names (`RegisterClient` vs `Register_Client`), and lowercases for file names and directory names (`html/client.html`vs `HTML/Client.html`. Doesn't affect the software per se, but it affects readability, and maintainability of your software. https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by filtering the data in python in your views.py . Use

```
ModelName.objects.filter(person_firstname="request").all()
```

and return the response as

```
return HttpResponse(ModelName.objects.filter(person_firstname="request").all())
```

If you want the returned data in JSON format then use

```
 return HttpResponse(json.dumps(list(ModelName.objects.filter(person_firstname="request").all())
```

Comment: I have added some code snippets to show what i currently have